# Security risk of @font-face with third party font not hosted by google

Tags: css, security, fonts, font-face

What are (if any) the security risks of having a externally loaded font into a css file via font-face. I can't see (again if any) a risk if the font was hosted by google but what if the external source wasn't hosted by Google.

If the file was ever compromised could this have adverse affects for the user or in fact the website?

Comment: A browser without bugs would simply reject any data that is not valid font data … the problems start with the browsers that do have bugs (so those in _reality_). And then the “effects” could be anything you can possibly imagine … buffer overflows, code injection, tainted memory, leaking of user data, … – take your pick.

Comment: To add on to what @CBroe says: this risk exists regardless of where the font data is hosted. While it's probably less likely to happen with Google-hosted data then from randomsite.ru-hosted data, the problems are on the client side (consuming the data), not the hosting side.

Comment: Thank you very much for these comments

Comment: It's also important to notice that the files expected are font files simply containing the font data. The data will be read - never executed as code. Any modern browser should as @CBroe said, reject the data - but if that's how it is in reality is dependent on other factors.